# Excel VBA TextToColum working partly with MS Project Dates

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

I am trying to parse the dates in an Excel sheet coming from MS Project.

```
11 May 2022 17:00
13 May 2022 17:00
23 July 2021 17:00
```

I am using

```
For Each c In Range("A1:ZZ1")
    If c.Value = "End" Then

        Columns(c.Column).TextToColumns Destination:=c.Columns, DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(0, 4)
    End If
Next
```

This works only for part of the cells, a lot stay as they were.
Using the Excel menue function TextTo Column it works fine.

```
12 March 2021 17:00
26.01.2022 17:00
09.02.2022 17:00
26 March 2021 17:00
```

Why could this happen?

EDIT: I am on German language normally, but it works with some and some not.
The weird thing is, it works fine with the standard Excel function, even with all German names.

Comment: Maybe a language issue?  What is the month `March` in the language of your Excel and/or Windows system.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld In German it is März. But see my edit. It works fine with the standard Excel function, only with VBA I get the problem.

Comment: VBA can sometimes be US-Centric (and its really a different program than Excel). As a test of your VBA code, I would suggest that, before running the VBA TTC code, you do a `find/replace` on your worksheet of  `März/March` and see if that makes a difference.  If it does, you have the answer (and also a possible work-around).

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Sorry for late feedback, but this is pointing in right direction. Because when I have exported it from MS Project in English, the Macro runs fine.